# OWL2 modelling a subclass with one different axiom

Tags: modeling, owl

I'm trying to model some lexical data using OWL 2 (DL, using Protege). My main class is "Lemma", which has a number of axioms (using Manchester syntax):

```
Every Lemma hasLanguage some Language. 
Every Lemma hasEtymology some Etymology. 
Every Lemma hasMorphology some Morphology.
```

etc.

I also have a class VariantLemma, which is basically a variant spelling of the original lemma, but it will always have the same language and etymology as its parent Lemma, but can have different morphology. I originally modelled it as being equivalent to:

```
Lemma and (isVariantOf some Lemma)
```

but how can I state that it'll have the same values as its parent lemma for all axioms except Morphology? Can I use property chains in some way?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Did the proposed solution end up working for you?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this.  In the situation that you have the

```
         isVariantOf             hasLanguage
lemma2 ---------------> lemma1 ---------------> language1
```

then you want to infer an additional propertty:

```
         hasLanguage
lemma2 ---------------> language1
```

Since you can find a path in the first graph from `lemma2` to `language1`, you assert that the second graph must exist by the following subproperty chain axiom. You need to do the same for the other properties, too, of course.

```
isVariantOf o hasLanguage SubPropertyOf hasLanguage
```

When you have an OWL reasoner and these axioms, then if you have assertions that about `lem1`, and that `lem2 isVariantOf lem1`, you'll see the inferred properties for `lem2`.  Here's a `lem1` and its properties in Protégé:

[image: object properties about lem1]

With the Pellet reasoner attached, the `hasEtymology` and `hasLanguage` properties are inferred for `lem2` (shown with a yellow background):

[image: inferred properties about lem2]

Here's the OWL ontology, if you're interested:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
    xmlns="http://www.example.org/lemmata#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.example.org/lemmata"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.org/lemmata#Morphology"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.org/lemmata#VariantLemma">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
      <owl:Class>
        <owl:intersectionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
          <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.org/lemmata#Lemma"/>
          <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty>
              <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.org/lemmata#isVariantOf"/>
            </owl:onProperty>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/lemmata#Lemma"/>
          </owl:Restriction>
        </owl:intersectionOf>
      </owl:Class>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
  </owl:Class>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.org/lemmata#Language"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.example.org/lemmata#Etymology"/>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.org/lemmata#hasEtymology">
    <owl:propertyChainAxiom rdf:parseType="Collection">
      <rdf:Description>
        <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/lemmata#isVariantOf"/>
      </rdf:Description>
      <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.org/lemmata#hasEtymology"/>
    </owl:propertyChainAxiom>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.org/lemmata#hasLanguage">
    <owl:propertyChainAxiom rdf:parseType="Collection">
      <rdf:Description>
        <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="http://www.example.org/lemmata#isVariantOf"/>
      </rdf:Description>
      <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.org/lemmata#hasLanguage"/>
    </owl:propertyChainAxiom>
  </owl:ObjectProperty>
  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.example.org/lemmata#hasMorphology"/>
</rdf:RDF>
```