# Does OWL DL include SubObjectPropertyOf and ObjectPropertyChain?

Tags: properties, owl, chain

I can not find clear statement, whether SubObjectPropertyOf and ObjectPropertyChain bring me out of OWL DL or not?

In this post [Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20182595/equal-relationship-between-ontology-properties/20199283#20199283) is mentioned: "In OWL 2 (but, unfortunately, not OWL 2 DL, as Antoine Zimmermann pointed out in the comments), you can assert that a given property is a superproperty of a chain of properties..."

And in this [Post 2](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17173081/owl2-modelling-a-subclass-with-one-different-axiom) is doesnt mentioned, whether solving that problem bringed out of DL.

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The explanation is in the [global restrictions section of the OWL 2 W3C docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Global_Restrictions_on_Axioms_in_OWL_2_DL)

Comment: Thank you @AKSW. I want to be sure that I got right. I have `:restOn owl:inverseOf :bears` and `:bears rdfs:subPropertyOf :locatedBelow` (so, all of them are not simple). Also I have ObjectPropertyChain `:bears :bears owl:propertyChainAxiom locatedBelow`, where `:locatedBelow` is transitive. Although I am dealing with not simple properties, I have the correct order  in my axiom (`bears` < `locatedBelow`) and according to subordination to `locatedBelow`:  `bears` < `locatedBelow` too. So I should be in DL, right?

Comment: You can use Protege tool which shows the OWL profile if you're not sure

Comment: The sentence you extract from Post 1 is misleading. Property chains are allowed in OWL 2 DL, but only under certain conditions, as explained in the link provided by AKSW. If you want to test that your ontology is in OWL 2 DL, you can use the OWL 2 validator: http://visualdataweb.de/validator/

Comment: @AKSW I read in few sources that Protege validator is not to 100% exact. Is it wright? Or you mean an other validator plugin?

Comment: @Antoine Zimmermann I am appreciated! Very usefull link!